# Showing image overflow from one div to another div

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Please refer the following links for image and diagram. [Image](http://i47.tinypic.com/kcif84.jpg), [diagram](http://i50.tinypic.com/xp1s10.jpg)   This is the sample image. Here "Messages" title is a separate div float at left "Joe Smith and you" div is float at right. In left side all the messages are in separate divs. Now i need to change the background image on hover as shown below (like a blue arrow). The background image need to overflow from left div to right div. I tried this following code but it wont works. It get cut appropriate to the div size. I need to show the full image like in the image.

```
 <div onmouseover="this.className='msgHover'"></div> `
```

above is the code on div. and my css class is

```
.msgHover
    {
        background-image: url('Images/MsgHighlight.png');
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just make the background image overflow the boundaries of the `div`. You can, however, make the whole `div` overflow it's own boundaries by using a negative right margin:

```
#mydiv:hover
{
    margin-right: -50px;
}
```

This will make the entire `div` go wider without pushing any other elements or affecting the layout of the site what so ever. This sounds like exactly what you're trying to do. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/yXRqD/).

Using this method you won't have to cheat using two `div`s in the first place and can just apply your background image on the one `div`.

---

Have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yXRqD/1/) where the right margin is animated to go negative on hover.

Comment: Thanks dude. It works great :) I got trouble more than 4 hours for this issue. Thanks lot. :) :)